# VLOOKUP Between two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA. I am trying to run a macro to open another workbook, filter, copy and paste a subset of data from this 2nd workbook into the 1st one. Then in the 1st workbook, have a vlookup formula with the table array and column index in the 2nd workbook. I can't seem to figure out the VBA portion. I also think there's an issue with my variables. Is anyone able to help please?

```
Sub VarMap()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cb As Worksheet
Dim ex As Worksheet

Set ex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SF SCD Bank Account")

'open 2nd workbook
SFmapping = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Cells(10, 4)
Workbooks.Open Filename:=SFmapping

'Not sure how to set variable for this 2nd workbook.
'The name of sheet changes with the date
Set cb = ActiveSheet

'filter in 2nd workbook, copy and paste this data
'into 1st workbook and delete it from 2nd
lastrow = cb.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
cb.Range("A1:H" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Cash Bucket"
cb.Range("B2:G" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ex.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
cb.Range("A2:H" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
cb.AutoFilterMode = False
cb.Range("B:B").Insert
cb.Range("B2").Select
cb.Range("B2").Formula = "=G2&H2"
cb.Range("B2").AutoFill Range("B2:B2" & lastrow)

'vlookup from 1st workbook to 2nd
lastrow2 = ex.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ex.Activate
ex.Range("A2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP=(H2,cb.Range(B:C),2,FALSE)"
ex.Range("A2").AutoFill Range("A2:A2" & lastrow2)

End Sub
```

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks Scott but i'm still getting an error. "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: `ex.Range("A2:A2" & lastrow2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP=(H2," & cb.Range("B:C").Address(0,0,xlA1,1) & ",2,FALSE)"` no need for the autofill.

Comment: sorry had a typo: `ex.Range("A2:A2" & lastrow2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(H2," & cb.Range("B:C").Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & ",2,FALSE)"`